# Can Select same query but cant delete error message came unkown column in mysql 5.6.17

Tags: mysql

```
select * from chbookmaster where acno='011000001401'



30  011000001401 2 2381 2390 TEST shiva 20140718 10 N (null) Y (null) (null) (null)



 delete from chbookmaster where acno = 011000001401

  1:18:13  [DELETE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  
  [Error Code: 1054, SQL State: 42S22]  
  Unknown column 'ACNO' in 'where clause'
  Code: 1054 SQL State: 42S22 --- Unknown column 'ACNO' in 'where clause'
 ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, 
 exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

```
 CREATE TABLE chbookmaster
     (
         TxnId bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         ACNo VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
         ChBookNo VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
         ChNoFrom INT NOT NULL,
         ChNoTo INT NOT NULL,
         Remarks VARCHAR(250),
         IssuedBy VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
         IssueDt VARCHAR(8),
         leafs INT DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
         Auth VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
         AuthBy VARCHAR(20),
         chargeflag VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
         LastUpdateBy VARCHAR(20),
         LastUpdateDt DATETIME,
         sno DOUBLE,
         PRIMARY KEY (TxnId)
     )
     ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Try to add quotes arround the value like your select statement.

Comment: @Jens Why would that cause the specific error above?

Comment: Please add the create statement of your table.

Comment: i already applied but same error gives i have all right with root access to.

Comment: @lc. It is only a guess.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnis That's ugly. Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24818044/edit) your question instead?

Comment: @Jens Fair enough. I'm thinking it's backticks and the way MySQL handles column name casing

Comment: I have tried in my own mysql db and the statement works fine.

Comment: @jen,@lc what exactly issue is is a kind of bug or any other issue.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnis I can`t say if it is a bug. It is very strange. Which version of mysql do you use? an windows or linux plattform?

Comment: its 5.6.17 and i am using both with windows as well as linux 2 .Its really very strange.

Answer (score 0):

chbookmaster is declared as varchar. You should enclose the value with single quotes.

```
delete from chbookmaster where acno = '011000001401';
```